# The Repository is Locked - Error while trying to commit into source control

Tags: xcode, git, version-control, commit

I was trying to commit files into my source control (Git) as usual, using Xcode 7.0.1 and from a point onwards I keep getting this message, disallowing me to commit changes into my source control:

[image: The Repository is Locked]

Anyone know how to resolve this?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It's just a common issue faced if two or more git operations are done by your system and that generates a lock file.

All you need to do is:

1. Close Xcode
2. Open the .git folder in your xcode project folder. The folder is hidden, so you would need to either use terminal to open the directory or the "Go to Folder" option in Finder.
3. Then delete the "index.lock" file. Either through terminal or Finder.
4. Try and commit again.
5. If it fails again, repeat 1 to 3 but commit first with terminal.

If you know what you're doing just typing this command into terminal in the current directory of your project and it should delete the lock file: `rm -f .git/index.lock`

If anything you can check this Quora question for more details on what you've faced: https://www.quora.com/Why-do-my-git-operations-often-fail-with-a-lock-error

Hope that helps you guys, and happy coding!

Comment: looks like it is working. what I did is went on the project folder, enabled hidden files, found the .git repository, found the index.lock file and renamed it to index.lock.old
This enabled the repository to create a new index.lock file so that it allowed me to commit..!

Comment: For commit with terminal:
1. open terminal
2. cd path folder
3. git commit -m "your commit message"

Answer (score 6):

Also make sure the simulator is not running while you are commiting.
Close both simulator and Xcode. then restart and try again

Answer (score 0):

1 . go to the project folder.
2 press 'Cmd+Shift+ .' button.
3 You get '.git' hidden folder.
4 Go to git folder.
5 delete 'index.log' file.
6 Commit again.

Comment: First time commit and push data from Terminal into the Mac.